# Cache queries using Parse Javascript SDK

Tags: javascript, caching, parse-platform

Is it possible to cache queries using Parse's (parse.com) Javascript SDK?

The only reference I've found is https://parse.com/questions/javascript-sdk-caching and it says that it is not currently supported.

Since last response to last link is from 4 month ago, I would like to know if it is supported now or if there are workarounds to cache this queries.

Answer (score 5):

with a little legwork, you can cache it (or about anything) yourself using a wrapper method.

for example, i modified https://parse.com/docs/js/symbols/Parse.Query.html to cache:

```
var cacheKeys = [],
    cacheVals = [];

function q(cls, ok, fail) { // query wrapper that implements caching

    // store or fetch from cache if available:
    var slot = cacheKeys.indexOf(cls);
    if (slot !== -1) {
        return ok(cacheVals[slot]);
    } else {
        slot=cacheKeys.length;
        cacheKeys.push(cls);
    }
    //normal query code:
    var query = new Parse.Query(cls);

    query.find({
        success: function(results) {
            cacheVals[slot] = results; //cache results 
            ok(results); // call traditionally 
        },

        error: fail || console.error.bind(console)
    });

} // end  q()
```

note that this can accumulate un-needed cache entries over time, so you may want to refactor with a WeakMap (if you can live with the browser support pool), maintain the cache yourself, or just let it build and reload every now and then. One other consideration is that it expects the EXACT same query object to be passed to q() each time. You can try to use JSON.stringify(cls) as a key, but results are not guaranteed. Still, since it's only a cache feature, a cache-miss due to a JSON key re-ordering wouldn't break anything...

Comment: The problem is that I couldn't use server info to cache (ie. did the element/collection change?)

Comment: Would you please elaborate how to use this method with constrains like limit, near, skip etc?

Comment: @IvanWang: if i understand the desire, i think you don't really need to modify anything to support constraints, you just need to memorize in the success handler and recall in the wrapper routine.

Comment: You can simple the cache by using object instead of array.

create: cacheVals = {};

set/get: cacheVals[cls]

Comment: @YechezkelDeren: the keys are objects, so they would all key under `[objectObject]` like that; no good

Comment: @dandavis Why? they are string representing the class name?

Comment: @YechezkelDeren: this caches response objects using query objects; no strings or classes...